# Sonata & EngineInterface Null

Tags: docker, symfony, twig, sonata-admin, symfony-3.4

I have an issue with twig and Sonata I think.
I don't really know from where does that comes, but I think it's because a composer update.

**My env :**

- Symfony 3.4
- Sonata admin bundle ^3.3
- Bower
- Grunt
- OsX 10.15
- Docker 19.03
- Docker Desktop 2.3

**Here's the problem :**

When i try to access my admin section (implemented with sonata admin bundle) I get this error :

`Type error: Argument 1 passed to \CoreBundle\Admin\Block\SearchUserBlock::__construct() must be a string or an instance of Twig\Environment or Symfony\Component\Templating\EngineInterface, NULL given.`

At the beginning, it cames only on my local docker env. But a commit has been pushed and now it's everywhere.

**I've tried :**

- Composer Install
- Remove vendors
- Composer Update
- Cache clear / assets regen

**Some clues**

- I solved this issue by re install ruby/compass on my local env. but it seems it's not a problem anymore.

If anybody has an idea, please feel free to save my life :)

Comment: Please edit your post and add some code to it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I've found a quick fix for that error:

**My Setup:**

- Symfony v4.4.10
- Sonata Admin Bundle v3.70.1

**Old services.yaml file**

```
admin.block.service.top_sales:
  class: App\Admin\Dashboard\TopSalesBlock
  arguments:
    - ~
    - '@sonata.templating'
  tags:
    - { name: sonata.block }
```

**Fix**

```
admin.block.service.top_sales:
  class: App\Admin\Dashboard\TopSalesBlock
  arguments:
    - '@twig'
    - ~
  tags:
    - { name: sonata.block }
```